# Unable to use field type "date" in composite unique key with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have Doctrine entity with a composite ID for stats entry like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="WA\CoreBundle\Entity\StatRepository")
 *
 */
class Stat
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand", inversedBy="stats")
 */
private $brand;


/**
 * this field is auto filled. Users should not be able to define it themself.
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=16, columnDefinition="ENUM('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')")
 */
private $type;


/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $date;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
private $value;


/**
 * Set type
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @return Stat
 */
public function setType($type)
{
    $this->type = $type;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get type
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getType()
{
    return $this->type;
}


/**
 * Set value
 *
 * @param string $value
 * @return Stat
 */
public function setValue($value)
{
    $this->value = $value;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get value
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getValue()
{
    return $this->value;
}

/**
 * Set brand
 *
 * @param Brand $brand
 * @return Stat
 */
public function setBrand(Brand $brand = null)
{
    $this->brand = $brand;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get brand
 *
 * @return Brand
 */
public function getBrand()
{
    return $this->brand;
}

/**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date
 * @return Stat
 */
public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->date = $date;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get date
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}
}
```

Whenever i try to insert new entry i get this error

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted
>   to string in
>   /..../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   line 1359

Leaving date field out of index allows me to add entries but i'd like to use it in index.

Is there any way to fix it?